# How to fetch location even when the app is minimised in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

A react native app that tracks location once user allows permmission to the app. The location should be tracked when the app is minimised also and with the location change every 5min a post request to Backend server with the location updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable geolocation in the background, you need to include the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in Info.plist and add location as a background mode in the 'Capabilities' tab in Xcode.
[react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

Comment: So does this thing work in case of android? I want the app to track location in every 5min interval even when the app is minimized.

Comment: Yes It works for android too. Use **watchPosition** to watch continuous location.  Get location on interval is not the best practice. Try using it's **distanceFilter**  prop which auto provide location when certain distance covered ( in meter )

Comment: No I don't want to get location on interval, I just want to send the latest location updates to the server after 5mins, which is possible right like a timer ?

Comment: You can get the current location after every 5 min by using **watchPosition** and adding distanceFilter to 0 and "interval" in milliseconds

Comment: Even when the app is in background right(both android & ios)?

Comment: Yes in both platforms :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library that allows you to do background task
https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task